# How can I get the top row of my table in beamer to be repeated in each slide when the table is long and gets divided over more than 1 slides

Tags: beamer, longtable, booktabs, allowframebreaks

I am using longtables along with booktab in my beamer slide and therefore trying to distribute the table over multiple slides using allowframebreaks command in the frame. The long table is coming correctly. However when the table goes to second slide, the first row of the table should be repeated which doesn't happen? How can I get that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools,nccmath}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}


% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{158, 27,50}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{158, 27,50}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{158, 27,50} % {130,138,143}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%------------------------------------------------------------
%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=0.75cm]{iitb1.png}} 

% logo of my university


\titlegraphic{%
\includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{example-image-duck}
}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\footnotesize}
\title[CL689]{Heat Integration Analysis for an Industrial
Ethylbenzene Plant using Pinch Analysis}%title
%\subtitle{ }%%subtitle
%\author[Priyam Nayak]{Priyam Nayak - 214026014\inst{1}}%%authors
\author[Priyam Nayak]{Priyam Nayak - 214026014}
%\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology Bombay\inst{1}}
\institute[IITB]{Indian Institute of Technology Bombay}
\date[\textcolor{white}{Project Presentation}]
{CL689 - Energy Integration in Chemical Processes\\ Project Presentation\\ Nov 22, 2022}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}
%    \frametitle{Contents}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
% ------Contents below------
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


% consider removing it if it's too redundant
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
}

%------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Problem Data - Cold Stream}
%\begin{table}
\begin{longtable}[c]{ccccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Stream} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{in}} & \textbf{T\textsubscript{out}} & \textbf{Heat Duty} & \textbf{Heat Capacity} \\
 & \textbf{($\degree$C)} & \textbf{($\degree$C)} & \textbf{(kW)} & \textbf{(kW/$\degree$C)} \\\midrule
\endfirsthead
%%
\endhead
C1 & 162 & 206 & 9020 & 205 \\
C2 & 158 & 200 & 3210 & 76 \\
C3 & 205 & 206 & 4445 & 4445 \\
C4 & 40 & 180 & 75 & 0.5 \\
C5 & 34 & 87 & 1007 & 19 \\
C6 & 241 & 242 & 8999 & 8999 \\
C7 & 221 & 244 & 5951 & 259 \\
C8 & 271 & 279 & 2105 & 263 \\
C9 & 55 & 130 & 230 & 3 \\
C10 & 33 & 90 & 2625 & 46 \\
C11 & 242 & 246 & 16989 & 4247 \\
C12 & 221 & 236 & 8082 & 539 \\
C13 & 268 & 282 & 3789 & 271 \\
C14 & 55 & 130 & 512 & 7 \\
C15 & 38 & 48 & 537 & 54 \\
C16 & 104 & 105 & 447 & 447 \\
C17 & 103 & 104 & 407 & 407 \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
%\caption{Cold stream data}
%\label{tab:cs-data}
%\end{table}
\end{frame}

\section*{Acknowledgement}  
\begin{frame}

\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\huge{\centerline{Thank you!}}}
\vspace*{0.5cm}

\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\Large{\centerline{E-mail: }}}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: pdf output of the latex code]

Comment: The `longtable` package has a nice manual.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to not show very long tables in your presentation

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I prefer to switch to portrait orientation, and get the audience to lie down

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am talking about cases where it's absolutely necessary for me to add the table.